# Power BI, Sum Values in One table based on criteria in another

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently running into an issue when trying to create a formula for a scenario. I currently have 2 tables that for simplification purposes look like this

Table 1

| Parent | Account | Level | Member-Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Taxable | 10000 | 3 | Base |
| Taxable | 20000 | 3 | Base |
| Non-Taxable | 30000 | 3 | Base |
| Non-Taxable | 40000 | 3 | Base |
| Income | Taxable | 2 | Non-Base |
| Income | Non-Taxable | 2 | Non-Base |
|  | Income | 1 | Non-Base |

Table 2

| Account | Company | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | Random Co. | 100 |
| 20000 | Random Co. | 200 |
| 30000 | Different Co. | 300 |
| 40000 | Random Co. | 400 |

The 2 tables are connected through account.

My current goal is to have a formula that would iterate through Table 1 and for any Non-Base items return a sum equal to all it's children, so it would look like the below if a slicer was applied to exclude Different CO.

| Account | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Taxable | 300 |
| Non-Taxable | 400 |

Currently I am trying to use the below measure but it does not return any values for the level 2 items.

1.SUMX(
Table1,calculate(sum(Table2[Amount]),PATHCONTAINS(Table1[Parent],SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[Name]))
)

Any assistance or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For your data sample correct DAX formula would look like:

```
Measure = 
SUM(Table2[Amount])
```

Both tables are connected through *Account* fields.

I put **Parent** field from **Table1** and **Measure** into table's *Values* and got your desired result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, going about it that way does work but I'm curious if there's a way I can still do it and use the Account column so I can see all accounts/parents at once.

Right now the way I was able to figure it was to insert new columns into Table2 and use the related function to grab the parent at each level for a specific account, set a relationship between table1 (Name) and Table2 (Parent Level x) and use a formula like this in a measure.

calculate(
        sum(Table2[Amount]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(Table2[Level_3],Table1[Name]))

Any suggestions to simplify?